# Why when i create an instance of class inside another it's become undefined?

Tags: javascript, class, animation, ecmascript-6, graphics

I am trying to draw a simple rectangle on canvas and move it around that's why I created loop class for animation and player class inside player I instantiated point class but when I try to use it inside the player update function it gives in console undefined why?

I am stuck I need help.

Class Main

```
// import zone
import Player from "./player.js";
import Loop from "./loop.js";

// var zone
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); // get canvas
let display = canvas.getContext("2d"); // get context
let loop;

// draw loop
function drawLoop() {
  loop = new Loop(canvas, display); // instance loop
  loop.update(); // update
  loop.draw(); // draw
  requestAnimationFrame(drawLoop); // loop
}
// invoke
drawLoop();
```

Class Loop

```
// import zone
import Player from "./player.js";
// class
export default class Loop {
  // init
  constructor(canvas, display) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.display = display;
    this.player = new Player(this.canvas, this.display);
  }
  // update
  update() {
    this.player.update();
  }
  // draw
  draw() {
    this.player.draw();
  }
}
```

Class Player

```
// import zone
import Size from "./size.js";
import Point from "./point.js";

// class
export default class Player {
  constructor(canvas, display) {
    this.display = display;
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.point = new Point(200, 200);
    this.size = new Size(100, 25);
  }
  // update
  update() {
    this.canvas.onclick = function(e) {
      console.log(this.point.x);
    };
  }
  // draw
  draw() {
    this.display.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    this.display.fillRect(this.point.x, this.point.y, this.size.w, this.size.h);
  }
}
```

Class Point

```
export default class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

it should return position x (a number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to call an instance variable inside of a block that has it's own "this" value. The pointer is however contained in the object's instance.

An arrow function will maintain lexial scoping and allow you to use the variable without binding "this" to the function:

```
this.canvas.onclick = (e) => {
  console.log(this.point.x);
};
```